# Sort objects by string propery, empty string last

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an array of objects which all contain string property. I want to sort objects by string property alphabetically in a way that objects with empty string property come at the end of the list. Currently I have this:

```
switches = switches.OrderBy(n => n.GetCurrentUser()).ToArray();
```

The problem is that it puts empty strings at the top of the list. How do I put objects with strings with value (sorted alphabetically) at the top and objects with empty strings at the bottom?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303481/how-to-put-empty-strings-at-the-end-when-sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
switches = switches
    .Select(n => new { TheObject = n, User = n.GetCurrentUser() })
    .OrderBy(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.User) ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(x => x.User)
    .Select(x => x.TheObject)
    .ToArray();
```

This will first build two groups, the one with empty user and others. `OrderBy` will move them to the end because 1 is more than 0. If you want them at the top use `OrderByDescending`.

Then i use `ThenBy` to sort alphabetically which will only matter for the non-empty users.

Answer (score 1):

OrderBy has an overload that [accepts an IComparer<>T](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__). This allows you to define your own sorting rules. You can start with the generic [Comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) class and override the `Compare` method, eg :

```
public class EmptyLastComparer: Comparer<string>
{
    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, creatre a new EmptyLastComparer() instance and pass it to `OrderBy` :

```
var myStrings = new[] { "c", "A","a", "A","b", " ","   ",null };
var ordered=myStrings.OrderBy(x => x, new EmptyLastComparer());
```

String comparison is more complex than just comparing two strings. [String.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) has overloads that allow case-insensitive comparisons, using specific cultures etc. The custom comparer could accepts a `StringComparison` parameter in its constructor to allow something similar, eg :

```
public class EmptyLastComparer : Comparer<string>
{
    private readonly StringComparison _comparison;

    public EmptyLastComparer(StringComparison comparison=StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    {
        _comparison = comparison;
    }
    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Compare(x,y, _comparison);
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps even add some predefined comparers, just like StringComparer does :

```
    public static EmptyLastComparer CurrentCulture =>
            new EmptyLastComparer();
    public static EmptyLastComparer CurrentCultureIgnoreCase => 
            new EmptyLastComparer(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    public static EmptyLastComparer InvariantCulture =>
            new EmptyLastComparer(StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    public static EmptyLastComparer InvariantCultureIgnoreCase =>
            new EmptyLastComparer(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    public static EmptyLastComparer Ordinal =>
            new EmptyLastComparer(StringComparison.Ordinal);
    public static EmptyLastComparer OrdinalIgnoreCase =>
            new EmptyLastComparer(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

And use them the same way, without allocating a new comparer each time :

```
var ordered=myStrings.OrderBy(x => x, EmptyLastComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use inline Comparer creation:

```
switches.OrderBy(n => n.GetCurrentUser(),                
                Comparer<string>.Create((a, b) =>
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(b)? 1 
                : !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) ? -1 
                : string.Compare(a, b)));
```